# Get attribute from a super class in python

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, subclass

I have a base class, a bunch of subclasses, and for each of these subclasses, I have another set of sub-subclasses. For example:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with open(config.txt) as f
            self.config_array = f.readlines()

class FirstOrderSubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class SecondOrderSubClass(FirstOrderSubClass):
    def __init__(self, name, version):
        self.name = name
        self.version = version
        super(SecondOrderSubClass, self).__init__(self.name)
        # needed to access self.config_array
        print self.config_array
```

I need to get the `__init__()` method of the `SecondOrderSubClass` to make the following assignment: `self.lines = self.config_array`.

EDIT: added line `print self.config_array`. If I run the code I get:

```
TypeError: __getattr__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: You are already inheriting the attribute, add `super(FirstOrderSubClass, self).__init__()` in the `FirstOrderSubClass`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access `self.config_array` until `BaseClass.__init__()` has run to set the attribute.

Either fix `FirstOrderSubClass` to also invoke the base class `__init__` or call it directly.

Fixing the `FirstOrderSubClass` is probably the best way to do so:

```
class FirstOrderSubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(FirstOrderSubClass, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
```

However, your `__init__` method signatures do not match so you cannot rely on cooperative behaviour here; as soon as you add a mix-in class in the hierarchy, things can and probably will break. See [*Python's `super()` is considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/*) by Raymond Hettinger, or it's followup [PyCon presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) to explain why you want your signatures to match.

Calling the `BaseClass.__init__` unbound method directly (passing in `self` explicitly) would also work:

```
class SecondOrderSubClass(FirstOrderSubClass):
    def __init__(self, name, version):
        super(SecondOrderSubClass, self).__init__(name)
        self.version = version
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
```

Note that there is no point in assigning to `self.name` there if you are going to ask `FirstOrderSubClass.__init__` to do the exact same thing.

The proper way to use `super()` is for all your methods to at least *accept* all the same arguments. Since `object.__init__()` never does, this means you need a sentinel class that does not use `super()`; `BaseClass` will do nicely here. You can use `*args` and `**kw` to capture any additional arguments and just ignore those to make cooperative subclassing work:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        with open(config.txt) as f
            self.config_array = f.readlines()

class FirstOrderSubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kw):
        super(FirstOrderSubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.name = name

class SecondOrderSubClass(FirstOrderSubClass):
    def __init__(self, name, version, *args, **kw):
        super(SecondOrderSubClass, self).__init__(name, *args, **kw)
        self.version = version
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This is precisely what I was missing. If the `BaseClass.__init__` doesn't run, of course, I cannot access anything into it! Many thanks also for pointing to the talk, I'm learning Python since few months now and I'm trying to read/watch anything I find.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `FirstOrderSubClass` `super` method:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with open("config.example.txt",'w') as f:
            f.write("Hello world")
        with open("config.example.txt") as f:
            self.config_array = f.readlines()

class FirstOrderSubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(FirstOrderSubClass,self).__init__()
        self.name = name

class SecondOrderSubClass(FirstOrderSubClass):
    def __init__(self, name, version):
        self.name = name
        self.version = version
        super(SecondOrderSubClass, self).__init__(self.name)
        # needed to access self.config_array

grandchild = SecondOrderSubClass("peter",2.0)
print grandchild.config_array
##>>> 
##['Hello world']
```