# Use super() in child class attribute to get parent class attribute

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, attributes, super

I want to get an attribute through the tree of inheritance of a class, with a class that I did not implement. I want to get its attributes in an unrestricted way. By "unrestricted way," I mean get the `_nameClass_` of a parent class without knowing the parent class.

Currently, all my classes have an attribute which represents their own name.

It handles me to use this class without getting its name, as with `eval()`, I'm able to initialize a parent class instance without knowing its name.

Example:

```
    class GrandParent(Library):
        _name_ = 'Grandparent'
        _instance_ = Library()

        def __init__(self):
            value = 0

    class Parent(GrandParent):
        _name_ = 'Parent'
        _parentName_ = super()._name_
        _instance_ = super()._instance_

        def __init__(self):
            value = 1

    class Child(Parent):
        _name_ = 'Child'
        _parentName_ = super()._name_
        _instance_ = super()._instance_

        def __init__(self):
            value = 2
```

Error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-119-03637faee91a> in <module>()
          5         value = 0
          6 
    ----> 7 class Parent(GrandParent):
          8     _name_ = 'Parent'
          9     _parentName_ = super()._name_

    <ipython-input-119-03637faee91a> in Parent()
          7 class Parent(GrandParent):
          8     _name_ = 'Parent'
    ----> 9     _parentName_ = super()._name_
         10
         11 
         12     def __init__(self):

    RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get attribute from a super class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501525/get-attribute-from-a-super-class-in-python)

Comment: It's not really a way to get `Class` attribut because they open an instance with `__init__()`.
 Futhermore, for calling the grandparent class, they use the name `baseClass` directly.
As I specified, it's not the way I wan't to make it work.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. As far as I know, `super()` is used to handle class instances, not the class itself. I mean, `super()` allows you to access methods from parent class which have been overriden in child class, but this happens where you work with objects of that class. Class attributes are already there with inheritance, you do not need to call `super()` to reset them, but you definitely need the name of the class to access them, like `_parentName_ = GrandParent._name_`, I am not sure there are other ways (maybe metaclasses? Not sure honestly).

Comment: I find a way to do it but i know it's a trash method : I'm using `super()` in the `__init__` function to update the class attribut value, which was init at `None`

Comment: That way however you will update the attribute each time you create a new instance of the class.

Comment: Yeah I know  but it's a temporary solution, I have to add a `ParentClassName._init_()` before have access to the Parent class properties